# EEFileNotFoundException/ Visual Studio 2012 crash only with debugger attached

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, interop

I've got a very strange problem that has me totally stumped.  I have a unit test like so:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void InitCaptureCard()
    {
        // This calls the constructor of a c++ class through
        // a c facade. All c++ unit tests pass.
        // the DLL containing this class is in the unit test directory
        // and all of its dependencies are dynamically loaded
        // the unit test, interop and native library are built for x86
        var card = new CaptureCardInterop.CaptureCard();

        // deletes the object
        card.Dispose();
    }
```

If I choose "run" on this test it passes as expected.  However, if I choose debug the test doesn't start.  Instead I get an `EEFileNotFoundException` if I have native exception handling turned on or simply crashes visual studio if I don't.  The stack trace for the dead test runner process looks like

```
clr.dll!Debugger::FirstChanceSuspendHijackWorker(struct _CONTEXT *,struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD *)  Unknown
clr.dll!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerShim(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *)   Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()    Unknown
clr.dll!_SignalHijackStartedFlare@0()   Unknown
clr.dll!Debugger::FirstChanceSuspendHijackWorker(struct _CONTEXT *,struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD *)  Unknown
clr.dll!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerShim(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *)   Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()    Unknown
clr.dll!_SignalHijackStartedFlare@0()   Unknown
clr.dll!Debugger::FirstChanceSuspendHijackWorker(struct _CONTEXT *,struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD *)  Unknown
```

which continues until it "triggers a break point" (i.e. just before a stack overflow).

I am stumped because **normally** `EEFileNotFoundException` means that it can't load a native DLL or one of its dependencies, but if that were the case I would expect similar behavior regardless of if a debugger is attached.

**Update**: After trying a bunch of stuff. Copying everything to new projects in a new solution that is not integrated with our build system causes everything to work as expected. So at least I know more or less where the problem is.

**Update 2**: Enabling Native Debugging is what triggers the crash.

Comment: Your stack trace is showing the managed debugger trying to deal with the exception notification.  And clearly flailing at it.  Never underestimate the ability of native code to thoroughly destroy the execution state of the program to the point that the debugger can't operate correctly anymore either.

Comment: @HansPassant While undoubtedly true, a break point on the first line of DllMain does not get hit so any native code that is running is Microsoft provided library loading code.